# Is it possible that we can run sneakers along with web server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rabbitmq, amqp, bunny, sneakers

I can use rake sneakers:run it work perfect. but can I run sneakers along with web server without running separate command (rake sneakers:run)

Answer (score 0):

you could check into https://github.com/ddollar/foreman to run another process using a single configuration "Procfile". Basically the way Heroku does it. A declarative process file that lets you run both web and workers in a single command.